# MySQL query not displaying all data when using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having some trouble fetching exact data from my database. I don't know what to do to achieve what I am looking for. I need some help in here. Here what I am facing...

Table name: ambulance

```
+----+---------+
| ID | CONTACT |
+----+---------+
| 01 | 1234567 |
| 02 | 2345678 |
| 03 | 3456789 |
| 04 | 4567891 |
+----+---------+
```

Table name: category

```
+----+----------+
| ID | CATEGORY |
+----+----------+
| 01 |    AC    |
| 02 |  Non AC  |
+----+----------+
```

Table name: multi_category

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| ID | AMBULANCE_ID | CATEGORY_ID |
+----+--------------+-------------+
| 01 |      01      |      01     |
| 02 |      01      |      02     |
| 03 |      02      |      01     |
| 04 |      02      |      02     |
| 05 |      03      |      01     |
| 06 |      04      |      02     |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

These are my table structures.

And now when I am applying this query

```sql
SELECT
    amb.ID,
    amb.CONTACT,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.CATEGORY SEPARATOR ', ') AS CATG
FROM
    ambulance as amb
LEFT JOIN multi_category as mct ON
    amb.ID = mct.AMBULANCE_ID
LEFT JOIN category as cat ON
    mct.CATEGORY_ID = cat.ID
GROUP BY
    amb.ID
DESC
```

The result I am getting is completely okay and the result is...

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID | CONTACT |    CATG    |
+----+---------+------------+
| 01 | 1234567 | AC, Non AC |
| 02 | 2345678 | AC, Non AC |
| 03 | 3456789 |     AC     |
| 04 | 4567891 |   Non AC   |
+----+---------+------------+
```

But when I am applying this query from below

```sql
SELECT
    amb.ID,
    amb.CONTACT,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.CATEGORY SEPARATOR ', ') AS CATG
FROM
    ambulance as amb
LEFT JOIN multi_category as mct ON
    amb.ID = mct.AMBULANCE_ID
LEFT JOIN category as cat ON
    mct.CATEGORY_ID = cat.ID
WHERE
    cat.ID = 01
GROUP BY
    amb.ID
DESC
```

I am getting this result..

```
+----+---------+------------+
| ID | CONTACT |    CATG    |
+----+---------+------------+
| 01 | 1234567 |     AC     |
| 02 | 2345678 |     AC     |
| 03 | 3456789 |     AC     |
+----+---------+------------+
```

You can see in the **CATG** field **Non AC** is missing. But **ID - 01 & 02** ambulance are both AC & Non AC.

Now my question is, how do I bring back Non AC in the CATG field with the second query with a WHERE Claus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE` on one of it's columns doesn't make sense. Did you mean `LEFT JOIN...AND...` or did you want an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @Bearded because you are filtering by category=01 which is `AC` category

Comment: @Strawberry: changing `where` to `and` would generate `null` category for ambulance `4`

Comment: @Bearded: Please provide your desired output

Comment: I want Non AC too while filtering with AC in the CATG field. You can see I am getting 3 sets of result from the second query but 2 of them are AC and Non AC ambulance and only one of them is AC. @AbhishekGinani

Comment: I changed WHERE to AND but its not working. @Strawberry

Comment: 'Not working' is rarely a useful diagnosis

Comment: How many categories are there?  Is the list of categories open-ended?  Are there any other columns in the `categories` table?  Depending on the answers, I would argue for a different implementation, possibly involving a `SET`.

Comment: @RickJames No, there are no other column in the `categories` table.

Comment: @RickJames could you please elaborate your different implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this will do the job for you, as you want to retrieve all the categories for an ambulance id as long as at least one of the categories match.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    amb.ID,
    amb.CONTACT,
    T.CATG
FROM
    ambulance as amb
LEFT JOIN multi_category as mct ON
    amb.ID = mct.AMBULANCE_ID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT mct.AMBULANCE_ID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.CATEGORY SEPARATOR ', ') AS CATG
FROM multi_category as mct 
LEFT JOIN category as cat ON
    mct.CATEGORY_ID = cat.ID
GROUP BY mct.AMBULANCE_ID) T
ON T.AMBULANCE_ID = amb.ID
WHERE
    mct.CATEGORY_ID = 01
ORDER BY
    amb.ID
DESC
```

Comment: :) Perfect. It's working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the second select you have the where clause

```
WHERE
    cat.ID = 01
```

this is limiting the result set to only `AC`

If you want to get both `AC` and `Non AC` remove the where clause.